# fortran Do loop index issue for optimize code

Tags: matrix, optimization, indexing, fortran, column-major-order

First of all my english is not good. I'm Sorry.

As far as I know. Fortran address is column major.
My old Fortran code is not optimized for long time.
I try to change my Fortran90 code index for better speed.

A code is almost 3-dimension matrix. (i, j, k)
and almost Do-loop is about i and j. 
sizes of i and j are about 2000~3000 and k is just 2, it means x,y

my old code's index order is (i, k, j)

for example

```
Do j = 1 : 1500
    Do i = 1 : 1024
        AA(i, 1, j) = ... ;
        AA(i, 2, j) = ... ;
    end do
end do
```

There are a lot of these in my code.

So I changed the index order.
for example (i, j, k), (k, i, j), (i, k, j)
I think (k, i, j) is the best choice in fortran (column major).

but result is not.

all 3 case [ (i, j, k), (k, i, j), (i, k, j) ] are spend almost time.
(1961s, 1955s, 1692s).

My program code is so long and Iteration is enough to compare ( 32000 )

Below is my compile option.

```
ifort -O3 -xHost -ipo -qopenmp -fp-model strict -mcmodel=medium
```

I don't understand above result.
Please help me.

Thanks to read.

additionaly, below is one of my programs.
matrix L_X(i, :, j) is my target, : is 1 and 2

```
!$OMP Parallel DO private(j,i,ii,Tan,NormT)

do j=1,LinkPlusBndry
  if (Kmax(j)>2) then
     i=1; Tan=L_X(i+1,:,j)-L_X(i,:,j); NormT=sqrt(Tan(1)**2+Tan(2)**2)
     if (NormT < min_dist) then
        L_X(2:Kmax(j)-1,:,j)=L_X(3:Kmax(j),:,j)
        Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)-1
     elseif (NormT > max_dist) then
        do i=Kmax(j)+1,3,-1; L_X(i,:,j)=L_X(i-1,:,j); end do
        L_X(2,:,j)=(L_X(1,:,j)+L_X(3,:,j))/2.0_dp
        Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)+1
     end if
     do i=2,M-1
       if (i > (Kmax(j)-2) ) exit
       Tan=L_X(i+1,:,j)-L_X(i,:,j); NormT=sqrt(Tan(1)**2+Tan(2)**2)
       if (NormT < min_dist) then
         L_X(i,:,j)=(L_X(i,:,j)+L_X(i+1,:,j))/2.0_dp
         L_X(i+1:Kmax(j)-1,:,j)=L_X(i+2:Kmax(j),:,j)
         Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)-1
       elseif (NormT > max_dist) then
         do ii=Kmax(j)+1,i+2,-1; L_X(ii,:,j)= L_X(ii-1,:,j); end do
         L_X(i+1,:,j)=(L_X(i,:,j)+L_X(i+2,:,j))/2.0_dp
         Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)+1
       end if
     end do
     i=Kmax(j)-1;
     if (i>1) then
       Tan=L_X(i+1,:,j)-L_X(i,:,j); NormT=sqrt(Tan(1)**2+Tan(2)**2)
       if (NormT < min_dist) then
         L_X(Kmax(j)-1,:,j)=L_X(Kmax(j),:,j)
         Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)-1
       elseif (NormT > max_dist) then
         L_X(Kmax(j)+1,:,j)= L_X(Kmax(j),:,j)
         L_X(Kmax(j),:,j)=(L_X(Kmax(j)-1,:,j)+L_X(Kmax(j)+1,:,j))/2.0_dp
          Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)+1
       end if
     end if
  elseif (Kmax(j)==2) then
     i=1; Tan=L_X(i+1,:,j)-L_X(i,:,j); NormT=sqrt(Tan(1)**2+Tan(2)**2)
     if (NormT > max_dist) then
        do i=Kmax(j)+1,3,-1; L_X(i,:,j)=L_X(i-1,:,j); end do
        L_X(2,:,j)=(L_X(1,:,j)+L_X(3,:,j))/2.0_dp
        Kmax(j)=Kmax(j)+1
     end if
  end if
  do i=Kmax(j)+1,M; L_X(i,:,j)=L_X(Kmax(j),:,j); end do
end do

!$OMP End Parallel DO
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "You might also care to re-lay-out your arrays. If I was designing AA from the start, and if I expected most accesses to be across all elements in the fat dimensions, I'd put the thin dimension first," - If I understand the question this is precisely what Kyum is doing, and the questions is why is this not the fastest - he/she finds it appreciably slower than the original. Hence the confusion, which is shared by me at the moment ...

Comment: @Kyum Why this is happening is not at all clear to me. It would really help if you could include in your question a complete program which shows the same symptoms so people can experiment. Without it we are all guessing.

Comment: OK - I assumed he had swapped the indices in the declaration of the array and in the loop nest in the same way. I'll wait until the OP provided a complete program then, as given we have read this in different ways it's obviously not clear what is being asked.

Comment: Everyone I'm sorry above my code was incorrect. Do-loop index order is  first J and I. So Do j = 1500 ; Do I = 1024 ; This is correct

Comment: and How do i upload my program on stackoverflow?

Comment: Don't put the whole program here - probably none of us have time to look at and understand any code that is more than 100 or so lines long. Create a cut down version of it that shows the same symptoms (here set up your matrices, one loop nest and some timers should do, with a way to check the results as well) and put it in a code block in your question

Comment: Please, DO include the declaration of the relevant variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry so much about loop ordering. ifort -O3 optimization is an aggressive loop optimizer. Its possible that reordering your 3-D arrays will have little to no affect.

As far as you thinking (k,i,j) is the best order. In general this would be best. But k only has 2 elements and i has 1024. Assuming you are using single precision real (4 bytes) This 2-D segment of your 3-D array fit in 8K ram. It is likely that your data, once the loop starts, is entirely on the CPU cache so index ordering would be irrelevant. You need much larger data dimensions for the effect your considering to take effect.

As far as your performance difference, that is likely the struggles of compiler optimizations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've learned something new about the compiler and the cpu cache. i use double precision, about half indexes are on cache?

Comment: i only thought register size, so (2,i,j) has least load time and doesn't waste register. Sadly, it was only my thought and it was not true.